# Persistence in Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to show a screen on my app only the first time I launch the app.
For this I was thinking into having a variable called `screenPassed` and set it as true when the person has finished reading the screen.

I was thinking into doing this by calling the segway that gets me to the "main" screen of my app, something like this:

```
partial void goToInitialScreen(){
    if(!screenPassed){
        this.PerformSegue("InitialScreen", this);
    }
}
```

Of course, this would mean that I would require to have persistence to save the state of screenPassed, and I would require not only to write to the persistence method but also read and restore state from that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store that boolean in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
using (var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults)
{
    var screenPassed = defaults.BoolForKey("screenPassed");
    if (!screenPassed)
    {
        defaults.SetBool(true, "screenPassed");
        this.PerformSegue("InitialScreen", this);
    }
}
```

re: [Working with User Defaults](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/user-defaults)